# Why gitlab-runner run execution as ruby docker when i set executor as shell?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

gitlab-ci

```
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - cp -R build/* /var/www/html
```

pipeline:

```
 Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:28
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
```

Why docker ruby? Why not shell executor?

my config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]

    name = "test"
    url = "https://gitlab.com/"
    token = "123321123"
    executor = "shell"
    shell = "bash"
```

Answer (score 4):

You most likely have shared runners enabled on the repository, and it just so happens that when the job is submitted, that the job picks up the shared runner first, rather than your custom shell runner.

So an option available is to [disable shared runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#disable-shared-runners) for your project:

- Go to Project's **Settings** > **CI/CD**
- In the **Shared runners** section, disable **Enabled Shared runners for this project**.

---

A better solution would be to enable [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/#use-tags-to-limit-the-number-of-jobs-using-the-runner) on the Runners.

When [registering](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) the runner, at step 5, you can provide tags associated with the runner. You can also change the tags in the GitLab UI if you have sufficient permissions in:

```
gitlab.com -> group -> settings -> CI/CD -> runner settings
```

Note, the tags are not changeable in the `config.toml` file.

You can now, for example, `tag` your runner with `shell-internal`, and then to run jobs only on this runner,  add `tags: - shell-internal` in your `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
build:
  script:
    - echo "running on shell-internal"
  tags:
    - shell-internal
```

---

This link should explain how GitLab runners work: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/